# Русские буквы в GET-запросе на Android

Tags: android, java, get

Пытаюсь на андроид послать get запрос и получить ответ. Проблема возникает в том, что не могу в запросе использовать русские буквы, потому что вместо них посылаются вопросики.
Код самого запроса:

```
URL url;
String result = null;
try {
    url = new URL("Строка запроса");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder allpage = new StringBuilder();
    int n = 0;
    char[] buffer = new char[40000];

    while (n >= 0) {
        n = rd.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (n > 0) {
            allpage.append(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
    result = allpage.toString();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Надо закодировать такие параметры запроса с помощью [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) и указав правильную кодировку, например, UTF-8. В противном случае вы, ясное дело, будете посылать на сервер фигню.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class URLEncoderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=" + URLEncoder.encode("Мария", "UTF-8"));
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            int rc;

            while ((rc = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                System.out.write(buffer, 0, rc);
            }

            System.out.println();
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот более полный пример. Просто русские слова заменяете на закодированные. Для примера выше запрос будет выглядеть

> http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, понятно что нужно кодировать. Просо очень плохо в этом разбираюсь пока что и в интернете на данный момент не нашла ничего более менее понятного. Хотелось бы увидеть небольшой примерчик.

Comment: Так вот же он, я привёл его. Просто когда делаете строку запроса при создании URL надо все параметры, которые могут содержать не ASCII-буквы прогонять через URLEncoder, как я сделал в примере для параметра _parameter_.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, Вылетает именно на этой строчке...
http://depositfiles.com/files/2yq5evys8

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, просто вы исправили, когда я уже открыла и у меня не отобразилось

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, если кодировать именно параметры, то все выходит, а если всю строку, то все валится. Странно это, но все же это рабочий вариант. Большое спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Ничего странного. Если весь запрос превратится в гору кодированных процентами символов, то URL становится невалидным.

Answer (score 3):

Машенька,

Проверьте-ка кодировку исходника, с большой долей вероятности ваш Java исходник написан под Win-1251, а надо бы под UTF-8.

Это я просто к тому, что вы хардкодите get запрос `url = new URL("Строка запроса");` прямо в исходниках, а он задан в кодировке Win-1251 так и уходит на сервер. Не скажу что это плохо, но ничего хорошего здесь тоже нет.

Универсальный рецепт: когда пишете под Android применяйте кодировку исходников UTF-8 - меньше будет проблем. Краткая инструкция как это сделать для Eclipse: [фтыкайте сюда](http://www.martinahrer.at/2007/06/03/eclipse-encoding-settings/)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать utf-8 кодировку для страницы.

Я могу ошибаться с решением, но насколько я помню меня спасало в аналогичном случае такое решение.

Comment: @Сергей, для какой именно страницы?
Сам запрос должен в результате получить xml с сервера. В обычном браузере все получается, а с Андроида не могу именно запрос послать, потому что вместо нормального параметра, написанного на русском, на серв отправляются вопросики

Comment: Прошу прощения, тут с Java запрос...
Значит ответ должен быть несколько другим.
Попробуйте в приложении форсировано перекодировать текст который посылаете в utf-8, если получатся хотя бы странные символы а не вопросы - значит копаем в правильном направлении.

Comment: @Сергей, что-то ничего доброго не выходит.

Comment: http://citforum.ru/internet/javascript/java_rbint.shtml

Быть может поможет что то из этого